# How to set http request queue length when self hosting webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Running ASP.NET WebApi I would like to set the HTTP request queue length.

I found some [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2015/03/11/request-and-connection-throttling-when-self-hosting-with-owinhttplistener.aspx) indicating this should be possible on [OwinHttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.host.httplistener.owinhttplistener(v=vs.113).aspx) and also in the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.owin.host.httplistener.owinhttplistener.setrequestqueuelimit(v=vs.113).aspx) .

So I used this approach to get the OwinHttpListner

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var owinListenerName = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener";
    var owinListener = (OwinHttpListener)appBuilder.Properties[owinListenerName];
    // more code...
}
```

But the method **SetRequestQueueLimit** was not there. Using ILSpy also showed that there is no such internal method on that class.

I'm using nuget package **Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener 2.0.2**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that there was a later version available so I did an update of all my nuget packages which updated the package **Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener** to version **3.0.1** and then the method was present.

Using netsh like:

```
netsh http show servicestate
```

verifies that the value of the request queue was actually updated.

I think it was because I originally installed the package **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost** which had a dependency on **Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener 2.0.2** or higher which was the reason I got the old version.

Hopefully someone else will be helped by this...